# How to backup IIS 7 website

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, iis-7, visual-studio-2008

I need to make a small code change to a Visual Studio 2008 web application hosted on IIS 7 with Server 2008 Standard. I don't know what was done with the web application in the past (afraid that code changes in visual studio don't match what's on the live server) but I want to be able to revert back to the old version of the web app if the code that is in the solution is different than what is in the live application.

How do I backup AND restore the website config and files if I run into issues and need to revert the web application back to it's original condition?

Comment: Just make a backup (file-copy) of the files, and copy them back in case something goes wrong.